# How to use TinyMCE in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce, nuxt.js, script-tag

I want to add this script to my Nuxt code:

```
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "#mytextarea",
    plugins: "emoticons",
    toolbar: "emoticons",
    toolbar_location: "bottom",
    menubar: false
  });
</script>
```

I can just throw it into my component's template body (**This script has to be inside `<body>` not `<head>`)** like this:

[image]

and interestingly enough it works but there are two issues here:

1. It looks ugly
2. It's not dynamic. For example I can't bind `selector` dynamically to a prop or a data property! It has to be hardcoded.

So I was wondering if anybody knows how can I integrate such scripts into my Nuxt project properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I really really doubt this works. Vue always ignores any `<script>` tags in the templates with error message:

> Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as `<script>`, as they will not be parsed.

2. There is no reason to put this into the template. It is just a regular JS code you can execute as part of the component lifecycle. Below is **very** simple component wrapper that integrates TinyMCE into Vue app.

However **I do not recommend doing this by yourself** and instead use [official Vue wrapper](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue) ([docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/)) - use [v3](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue/tree/v3.x) for Vue 2. Official integration handles all the edge cases like component activation/deactivation (when used together with `<keep-alive>`) and proper cleanup when the component is destroyed which is required in order to avoid [nasty memory leaks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

```js
const ed = Vue.component("MyEditor", {
  props: ["id", "value"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <textarea :id="id" :value="value"></textarea>
    </div>
  `,
  mounted() {
    const me = this;
    window.tinymce.init({
      selector: "#" + this.id,
      plugins: "emoticons",
      toolbar: "emoticons",
      toolbar_location: "bottom",
      menubar: false,
      setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on("change input undo redo", function () {
          me.$emit('input', editor.getContent({format: 'text'}))
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/liwoj/pen/KKNeOoY)

### Nuxt

As TinyMCE is completely JS rendered, it does not make sense to execute it during server side rendering. In fact, above code will not work at all on server as there is no `window` variable. Use Nuxt's `<client-only>` [component](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#the-client-only-component) to force Nuxt to render editor only on the client...

UPDATE: On the other side the `mounted` lifecycle hook is not called during SSR at all so maybe this will work just fine even without the `<client-only>`

Comment: It actually worked. Thanks. However could you please give me an explanation for the `setup: function (editor)` part? What does it do and why do we need to add it there?

Comment: Yes I know it works but as I said, don't use my code. It is missing very important part - destroying editor when component is destroyed. I could add it but it seems as waste of time if there is official integration for Vue from the authors of TinyMCE. The know their editor better....

Comment: [setup](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup) is a function called by TinyMCE. It is useful for setting up event handlers. In my example I handle events emitted when content of editor is changed in order to emit Vue `input` event - this makes `v-model` on the component work...

Comment: Aha makes sense. There are more scripts from other sources I want to integrate most of which don't have official integration for Vue. How do you suggest I go on about integrating them?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, the official vue package is the way to go. Even with the official package, there were a number of issues once I pulled it into Nuxt.

Here's a step by step of how I got it working. Here are the versions of everything involved:

```
    "tinymce": "^5.10.3",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3.2.8",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "nuxt": "2.15.8",
```

The tinymce-vue package requires a tinymce to be available. You can either install it via npm like above, or use the cloud-hosted version (see [Prerequisites here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#prerequisites)).

### Nuxt-specific Issues

You'll need to ensure the component is wrapped in the `<client-only>` tag to avoid SSR errors.

Additionally, if self-hosting the tinymce package, you'll want to only import it on the client-side. Otherwise you will see errors like:
`[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: ... Reason: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`

You can do this by using `require` and `if (process.client) {` around them.

Ex:

```
if (process.client) {
  require('tinymce/tinymce')
  require('tinymce/themes/silver')
  require('tinymce/icons/default')
  require('tinymce/plugins/lists') // do this for any plugins you use on the editor
}

import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
```

At this point the editor should be loading on your page, but styles are probably not loading.

You can fix this by adding `require('tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css')` below the other `require`s.

Now the styles will be fixed but the tinymce theme will still look for other CSS files like mobile, min versions on its own, and cause network errors.

Ex:

```
404 http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css
404 http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css
```

**For content:**
You can either copy that file to the static folder with the same path, or override them with the [content_css setting](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css) (in the Vue component `init` options).

**For skin:**
Since you already provided it as a module, set `skin: false` in the Vue component `init` options.

UPDATED 2022-11-29: Fixed Typo