# Can I use Tinymce-vue without a no-api-key CDN?

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

This is for an internal web application.
Tinymce-vue injects a no-api-key CDN into my application. This was ok but now I'm in the process of migrating my app to a new server that does not have internet access and this is breaking the app.
Is there any way around this.
Thanks

Vue2
tinymce-vue 3
tinymce 5
All npm loaded packages.

Comment: The question presumes that it's known that it can be used with CDN only, while this is not so. If this happens to you when you use CDN, then you probably shouldn't use it

Comment: The CDN is injected by the package. I have the code installed locally.

Comment: Which package? The question doesn't explain your problem fully. This is very specific to your case, which is unknown. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . As shown in the docs, https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#prerequisites , it's up to you to use CDN or not.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that the package 'Tinymce-vue 3' programmatically injects the CDN link into the html out of my control. I did not realize this until I moved to a server not connected to the internet.

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What you describe is not something that goes without saying. It's unknown if there's a mistake on your side with the library use or the problem with the lib itself. Either way, this requires additional info from you in order to be examined. See the link above, this is a requirement for SO questions. It's possible  that you just didn't use this https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/vue-ref/#tinymce-script-src or global tinymce.

Comment: Just found this: [TinyMCE Vue Integration SelfHosted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67425439/7222906)
Its gotten me a little closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of:
[TinyMCE Vue Integration SelfHosted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67425439/tinymce-vue-integration-selfhosted)

TinyMCE needs to be imported before TinyMCE-vue or it gets pulled from CDN.
More than one import of TinyMCE-vue was causing the issue for me.
The linked issue has more information on importing plugins, skins etc. while self hosting.